# Celery - No module named five

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, celery, django-celery

After updating celery and django-celery to 3.1:

```
$ pip freeze | grep celery
celery==3.1.18
django-celery==3.1.16
```

I run into this error when starting my server:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "app/manage.py", line 16, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  [...]
  File "/Users/xxx/.virtualenvs/yyy/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 42, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "/Users/xxx/.virtualenvs/yyy/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 95, in __init__
    raise ImportError("Could not import settings '%s' (Is it on sys.path?): %s" % (self.SETTINGS_MODULE, e))
ImportError: Could not import settings 'settings' (Is it on sys.path?): No module named five
```

Using:

- Django 1.4.21
- Python 2.7

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Last version of vine is 5.0.0 and fresh push was in 06.09.2020 (yesterday) :), and this version  do not have any `five.py` file. So downgrade vine version to.

`vine==1.3.0`

works for me

UPDATE: by the answer Sarang, amqp and celery now requires `vine>=5.0.0`

Comment: Thank you. My CI pipeline was failing and i was wondering why!

Comment: This isn't an option anymore if you use latest versions (as of May 2022). `amqp` now needs `vine 5.0.0`

Answer (score 4):

Some suggestions found in internet were:

- Reinstall both (because of a celery and django-celery version mismatch)
- Upgrade celery

What worked for me was to upgrade kombu:

```
pip install kombu -U
```

NOTE: after updating to celery 3.1, django is supported [out of the box](http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/django/first-steps-with-django.html#using-celery-with-django).

Comment: Upvoted; upgrading Kombu is the correct approach now. Kombu removed references to five a while ago. See https://github.com/celery/kombu/commit/1916b815f88551138ff26eda3e4af4c519c893e3#diff-f29e90d1926b0c9801f74a90de0c7410960c998fda329785546b7f7ccbd49600

Answer (score 2):

You need to create a celery app according to new celery setup. Create a file celery.py in your project folder with settings.

```
from __future__ import absolute_import

import os
import sys

from celery import Celery


sfile = 'mysettings_file' # override it
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', sfile)


from django.conf import settings

project_name = 'referral' # override it

app = Celery(project_name)
app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings')
app.autodiscover_tasks(lambda : settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
```

In your `app/tasks.py`, add your task

```
from referral import celery_app # substitute your project folder

class MyTask(celery_app.Task):

     pass
```

Then, use this app to register your tasks. Infact, you don't need `djcelery` if you want to use celery with django, unless you are using it as database backend.

Answer (score 2):

- i face this kind of issue...

```
from kombu.five import PY3, values
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'kombu.five'
```

- after that reinstall celery by
- `pip install celery`
- this way i fix this issue in my machine :)

Answer (score 1):

As of version 5.0.0 celery do not use five or six. It's python 3 only. if you use the latest pypi release, you won't face it. celery 3.1.x and 4.4.x is EOL now.

Answer (score 1):

I am on latest (kombu==5.2.4, celery==5.2.6) and still got this error! I thought I will share my experience. I read answers here and tried to downgrade `vine` to `1.3.0`. However, that is not possible as `kombu` needs `amqp` latest which needs `vine` latest!

While I was trying all this, I went back to the latest versions and the error magically disappeared. So not sure what it was, but could be the `re-install celery` fix that some people have shared here.

But happy to report that the latest (May 2022) combination of `kombu==5.2.4, celery==5.2.6, amqp==5.0.9, vine==5.0.0` is working fine!

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue, it was due to dependency of kombu and vine when we use celery. **kombu**==5.0.2 and **vine**==5.0.0 giving issue with **celery**==4.4.2.

In latest version of vine, vine.five module was not found inside five.py in celery package.

```
  File "/home/vin/test/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/five.py", line 7, in <module>
import vine.five
```

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'vine.five'

**Solution:** Just reinstall the celery package again it will downgrade vine to 1.3 and kombu to 4.6.11 as per its compatibility.

```
pip install celery
```

Comment: Not an option anymore if you want to be on latest